# HTML, CSS; How to prevent color shining through overlaying divs

Tags: html, css, colors

Let's say I've the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html    {
    background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
}
div {
    background-color:rgba(9, 7, 7, 0.23);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text `div` has a dark green background color although the background color is grey. You can check this by removing the background color from `html`.

It's because the green color is shining through the grey div. Is there a way to "say" the text `div` take `background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);` but use white as background color?

Comment: If you change `background-color:rgba(9, 7, 7, 0.23);` to `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);` is that the result you're looking for?

Comment: if i understand correctly this should do it color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);background-color:#fffff;

Comment: Add one white background div over grey div.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second problem

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body    {
    background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
}
div {
    color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
    background-color:white;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I read `"Is there a way to "say" the text div take background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80); but use white as background color?"` So the white background color should be applied to the div tag instead of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly this will do the trick (set the div background-color to be white and the div text color to be rgba(9, 7, 7, 0.23);)

https://jsfiddle.net/Lsjo988z/4/

html:

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

css:

```
html {
  background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
}
div {
  background-color:#fff;
  color:rgba(9, 7, 7, 0.23);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understood your question correctly then you should try this and see if that's what you're looking for.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body    {
      background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
  }
  div {
      color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80), rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80)),
                linear-gradient(white, white);
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Only the background element has been added to your code, so the color of the text is still the same, but it can be changed if you want.

Here's the thing:

You said the following

> It's because the green color is shining through the grey div. Is there
>   a way to "say" the text div take background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65,
>   0.80); but use white as background color?

That made me think you want to have 2 background colors as 2 different layers, one is green (rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80) and the other one is white.

If this is not what you meant, please give us more information (maybe you should draw the result you want).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you don't want to change the text color as the other answers are suggesting, but rather prevent the green from shining through your transparent `div` while still taking advantage of the alpha value to create a lighter color.  You could do as one commenter suggested and use an opaque color that will achieve the same end goal.  Or you could use a wrapper `div` to accomplish what you wanted.

If you wrap the transparent `div` with another wrapper `div` and target that to have a white background, it will stop the green from bleeding through.  You must set the `display` property to `inline-block` to "shrink wrap" around the child elements.

```css
html {
  background-color: rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

#inner {
  background-color: rgba(9, 7, 7, 0.23);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
html    {
    background-color:rgba(53, 135, 65, 0.80);
}
div {
    background-color:rgba(9, 7, 7, 0.23);
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:white;">
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```